# Uniqueness of analytic function

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume that $f$ is an analytic function defined on the unit disk and continuous up to the boundary. How many zeros can $f$ have in the unit disk?

Comment: Countably infinitely many, there is a construction somewhere in the exercises of Rudin's RCA book

Comment: Here's one idea that occurs to me, but I haven't sat down to check if all the technical details work. Take an infinite Blaschke product where you've arranged for the zeros to be at $1- 1/n^2$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product ) and then multiply by $z-1$ to kill discontinuity on the boundary at $z=1$

Comment: This (Yemon's idea) will work for sure since $B$ is holomorphic where zeros don't accumulate (so here at all $z\not=1$) and $|B|\le 1$, so multiplying by $z-1$ will make it continuous.

Comment: Maybe one can in fact characterize the zero sets of $A(D)$ functions in this way or get close to it, but of course that's a question someone must have thought about long ago.

Comment: Your title seems to bear little relation to your question.

Answer (score 6):

Well, a celebrated result of Fatou states that the family of zero sets of such functions on the boundary, i.e., the circle, are precisely the closed sets of (linear) measure zero. Of course, they can also have zeros in the open disc but these will be at most countable with all limit points on the boundary and the set of all such limits will be of zero measure. In addition, they must satisfy the Blaschke condion on the set of zeros of a bounded, holomorphic function in the open disc.